# Passing useState Hook into another function on React

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks, undefined, use-state

I want to pass in a boolean value in a useState hook that opens and closes a modal on click between two functions. However, I keep getting this error message: `Cannot destructure property 'setOpenModal' of 'props' as it is undefined.`

Main.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";    
import * as Materials from "../components/Materials"; // <- Material.js

const Main = () => {

    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false); //<- Opens (True) and Closes (False) Modal
    const { MaterialContainer } = Materials.MaterialTable(); // <-Calling Function Under MaterialTable

return (

    <MaterialContainer 
      openModal={openModal}
      setOpenModal={setOpenModal}
    /> 
    // This is how I am passing in Open/Close useState.
}
```

Material.js

```
export const MaterialTable = (props) => {

  const { openModal, setOpenModal } = props; // <- Pointed in Error Message.

  const openMaterialModal = (item) => {
    console.log("Button Clicked");
    setOpenModal(true); // <- Where I am passing in a true statement.
  };

  const MaterialContainer = () => (
    <>
        <Table>Stuff</Table>
    </>
  );
  return {
    MaterialContainer
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks so weird. There is no way for you to reach MaterialContainer except the inside of the MaterialTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MaterialTable` component is entirely malformed from a React perspective, though valid JavaScript.  It's just a normal function that defines a couple of constants and then returns nothing.  (Well, in the original question it returned nothing.  Now it returns an object.)

And when you call that function you indeed don't pass anything to it:

```
const { MaterialContainer } = Materials.MaterialTable();
```

So the `props` will be `undefined`.

Make `MaterialTable` itself a React component:

```
export const MaterialTable = (props) => {

    // destructure the props passed to the component
    const { openModal, setOpenModal } = props;

    // a function I assume you plan to use in the JSX below later?
    const openMaterialModal = (item) => {
        console.log("Button Clicked");
        setOpenModal(true);
    };

    // the rendering of the component
    return (
        <>
            <Table>Stuff</Table>
        </>
    );
}
```

Then just import and use that component, without trying to destructure anything from it or invoke it manually:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import the component
import { MaterialTable } from "../components/Materials";

const Main = () => {

    // use the state hook
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);

    // render the component, passing props
    return (
        <MaterialTable
          openModal={openModal}
          setOpenModal={setOpenModal}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked but it broke something else. XD What would you do if a useState "const [value, setValue]" lives and is being used in Material.js and would like "setValue" be used in Main.js as well?

Comment: @JaeWon: At its simplest that sounds like a scope error.  If the parent component needs to know about a given state, that state should be managed at or above that parent component, not in a child component.  But if we are to assume that the structure you have needs to be that way, then what you can do is have the parent component pass to the child component's props a function to invoke at a given event.  The child component can still maintain that state, but pass the updated value(s) to the parent component's callback function.  This can get pretty unwieldy pretty fast though.